# Reading password from stdin in lightdm

Tags: java, ubuntu, stdin

I don't know if this is a Java or Ubuntu problem, so I'll post here.

Due to a bug I worked under startx for a dew days, starting Eclipse from the terminal. In a program, i was mounting an external drive using the Runtime class

```
String[] command = {"gksu", "mount", "/dev/sdb1", "mounter/sdb"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

And i was prompted each time to type in the password. So I wrote this

```
String pwd = "mypassword"; 
System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(pwd.getBytes()));
```

And the command was executing well without asking for password (also worked with `sudo -S`)

But now I'm back working on lightdm and this doesn't work. When using `gksu` it prompts me for my password everytime and `sudo -S` does nothing.

```
String input;
while((input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(input);
}
```

This command actually displays my password in the console, but I still can't get the program not to ask me for the password.

The goal of the application is, among other criterias, to be fast, and this password thing is pretty annoying. I'd appreciate if any of you has suggestions.

Regards

Comment: srsly... you are trying to solve a problem you should not be having. If you really need to hardcode your pw into you application you are doing something wrong. If you really want to mount that stuff without entering a password configure your system such, that your program does not need to enter a password as well. (also you are missing a newline after your password - that might be due to the minimal example though, no idea)

Comment: If you're getting different behaviour based upon how you started X, then I suggest you run 'env' from the prompt in both modes and compare whats different.  I suspect there's something (a capability?) set in your session when running from lightdm that is not set when running from startx

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use the password, put it in a properties file so the program would be easily transferable from computer to computer. Couldn't get it to work with newline, so I modified mount and umount not to ask for a password, i'll have to explain the how to in a manual file then.